# Why is the batch size None in the method call of a Keras layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a custom layer in Keras. If I print the shape of the input passed to the `call` method, I get `None` as the first element. Why is that? Shouldn't the first element be the batch size?

```
def call(self, x):
    print(x.shape)  # (None, ...)
```

When I call `model.fit`, I am passing the batch size

```
batch_size = 50
model.fit(x_train, y_train, ..., batch_size=batch_size)
```

So, when is the method `call` actually called? And what is the recommended way of getting the batch size in the method `call`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`None` means it is a dynamic shape. It can take any value depending on the batch size you choose.

When you define a model by default it is defined to support any batch size you can choose. This is what the `None` means. In `TensorFlow 1.*` the input to your model is an instance of `tf.placeholder()`.

If you don't use the `keras.InputLayer()` with specified batch size you get the first dimension `None` by default:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))
print(model.inputs[0].get_shape().as_list()) # [None, 2]
print(model.inputs[0].op.type == 'Placeholder') # True
```

When you do use `keras.InputLayer()` with specified batch size you can define the input placeholder with fixed batch size:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((2,), batch_size=50))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))
print(model.inputs[0].get_shape().as_list()) # [50, 2]
print(model.inputs[0].op.type == 'Placeholder') # True
```

When you specify the batch size to the `model.fit()` method these input placeholders have already been defined and you cannot modify their shape. The batch size for `model.fit()` is used only to split the data you provided to batches.

If you define your input layer with batch size `2` and then you pass different value of a batch size to the `model.fit()` method you will get `ValueError`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((2,), batch_size=2)) # <--batch_size==2
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy')
x_train = np.random.normal(size=(10, 2))
y_train = np.array([[0, 1] for _ in range(10)])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=3) # <--batch_size==3
```

This will raise:

`ValueError: The`batch_size`argument value 3 is incompatible with the specified batch size of your Input Layer: 2`

Comment: You are not answering my questions. When is `call` called and what is the recommended way of getting the batch size in the `call` method? Why would we even have or need a dynamic size for the first dimension? Can't the first dimension be passed directly and explicitly?

Comment: I still don't get why we have `None` for the batch size. Why is that? Why don't even get rid of the `None`, if it is not usually specified, when the layer is defined (which I have not yet understood when it is the case)? What if I am using `Sequential`? So, to define the batch size for all layers, I would need to first add an `Input` layer to the `Sequential`?

Comment: "_The batch size for `model.fit()` is used only to split the data you provided to batches._", but what if the batch size specified in the `fit` method is different than the one specified in the placeholders?

Comment: In this case you will get `ValueError`. Appended to my answer

Comment: I personally have never used `InputLayer()`. But again, maybe there are some cases where it is useful to define a fixed batch size. For example, it can ease the implementation of certain operations you may define on the input.

Comment: Just a last question: when is the method `call` called?

Comment: The `call()` of the model is called during forward pass. The `model.call()` invokes `call()` methods of the defined layers one after the other, passing the values of the layers forward.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue and found that using `tf.shape(your_variable)` instead of `your_variable.shape` solved the problem. As `tf.shape(your_variable)` is dynamically evaluated later when the fit function is called.

reference
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36991#issuecomment-590448880

To get the value in integers consider output_shape variable.
Minimum working example

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((2,), batch_size=50))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, input_shape=(2, )))

print(model.output_shape)
print(type(model.output_shape[0]), type(model.output_shape[1]))
```

Output:

```
(50, 2)
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Yes, the tf.shape() is dynamically evaluated, but I'm not able to convert it to an int value inside the Call function.

Comment: @bestyasser edited the response. You could try output_shape parameter of your model object.